# Can not set style for the first row in kendo ui grid

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to set style for rows in kendo ui grid. This is my code:

// grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
          .Name("gridModel")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table" })
          .DataSource(x => x.Ajax()
                      .Read("ReadData", "General")

          )      
          .Columns(c =>
          {
              c.Bound(i => i.ID);
              ...........
```

// script

```
$("#gridModel").find("tbody > tr").addClass('myStyle');
```

// css

```
.myStyle{
background-color: #005850;
}
```

However, the rows at 0, 2, 4, 6, ... can not set background colour as my desire. I don't know what happen. Please help me!

Comment: what's your current outcome..?

Comment: `("tbody > tr:first-child")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to below steps:

1. Add event .Events(e => e.DataBound("changeBackgroundColor")) into your grid
2. Add javascript to handle the DataBound event

   `onDisableCheckControl: function () {
           var grid = $("Your Grid ID").data("kendoGrid");
           var data = grid.dataSource.data();
           $.each(data, function (i, row) {
               if (row.YourCheckAttribute != null) {
                   var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
                   $(element).addCss("change-background")

               }
           });
       }
   };`
3. Add CSS to change the background color
   yourgridId td{
     background-color: black
   }

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

to change color of first tr 
just use `tbody tr:first`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#gridModel").find("tbody > tr").addClass('myStyle');  
$("#gridModel").find("tbody tr:first").addClass('desirecolor'); 

})  


 </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8M7Cw/

Answer (score 2):

If your jquery is working fine ie adding `"myStyle"` class to first `<tr>`*(this you can check through inspect element)* then check your first `<tr>'s <td>` tags, surely they have some class or style applied to them which overrides `".myStyle"` properties